# ng-pattern disallowing special characters

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-pattern

I want to disallow these characters in my field /:*?"<>|
How should my ng-pattern look like? So far it looks like so:

```
ng-pattern="/^[\/:*?"<>|]*$/"
```

It is wrong as my IDE has problem with the " character in the middle. I want to exclude this character as well. This field should accept a filename. These characters are invalid.

Comment: use backslashes for special characters, so you need `\"`, and `/g` at the end of the regex pattern will make a global search

Comment: Like this? ng-pattern="/^[\/:*?\"<>|/g]*$/"

Comment: Still nothing. IDE complains

Comment: I meant `"/........./g"`

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with this     ng-pattern="/^[\/:*?\"<>|]*$/g"

Comment: `|` is an OR operator in regex, I'm assuming you need `\|` , and probably the same for `\?`

Comment: Nope, still nothing..

Comment: Add single quote `'`  ng-pattern='/^[\/:*?"<>|]*$/'

Comment: How can I test this? I have used <p ng-show=fileNameForm.fileNameInput.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Invalid characters</p> but it is being displayed all the time.